# How to add fragment to existing fragment dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I want to add a fragment to an existing fragment on a button press (button sits on parent fragment) but I get an error: java.lang.ClassCastException:  must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener.

What does that mean and why doesn't any of the example have it?

Parent fragment button press code:

```
Button interestedButton = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.interestedButton);
interestedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    InterestedFormFragment interestedFormFragment = new InterestedFormFragment();
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.interestedFrag_container, interestedFormFragment, "INTERESTED_FORM");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

Parent fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:id="@+id/buildingPageId">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/interestedFrag_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
...
```

The "interestedFrag_container" should hold the newly added child fragment.

My parent fragment isinflated and hold the button that should add the child.
What am I missing here?
Thank you!

Comment: Nested fragment are only added since API 17. Which API are you targeting ?

Comment: I think you awnsered your own question :) If the support is from API17 and up then I am going to have to target API17 or up to use nested fragements. Thank you for the question.

Comment: If it solved your problem I can write it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested fragment are only added since API 17.

You can use [getChildFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) to manage your nested fragments.